# Trouble with defaulting arguments in Flow

Tags: flowtype

Our codebase is stuck on version `0.79.1` of `flow-bin` and it seems that using default arguments isn't working as expected in this example:

```
function foo({a = 1}: {a: ?number}) {}
```

[Playground link](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBvAhogvIgRgF8AuRbMgfjBAFsAjAUwCciBKcogKC6A) (be sure to set the version to `0.79.1`

The error:

```
1: function foo({a = 1}: {a: ?number}) {}
                 ^ null or undefined [1] is incompatible with number [2].
References:
1: function foo({a = 1}: {a: ?number}) {}
                             ^ [1]
1: function foo({a = 1}: {a: ?number}) {}
                              ^ [2]
```

However, removing the `?` from the type works.

```
function foo({a = 1}: {a: number}) {}
```

When using the latest version Flow, both examples compile with no errors.

In our code, we're trying to default to `null`.

```
function foo({a = null}: {a: ?number}) {}
```

and this seems to fail for the same reason the first example did.

```
1: function foo({a = null}: {a: ?number}) {}
                 ^ null or undefined [1] is incompatible with number [2].
```

Is there a way to work around this error while also defaulting a value to `null`, annotating that value as a Maybe type, and keeping the version unchanged?

Comment: Is it acceptable to ditch the `= 1` in favor if doing `if (a === undefined) a = 1;` in the function body instead? It seems like the default is the core of the issue, the only benefit of using that syntax is that it is a bit shorter.

Comment: Good point, yeah that's acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a Flow bug to me, so if updating is not an option, then it seems like your only option is to not use default-assignment for the object pattern, in favor of doing that manually afterward, e.g.

```
function foo({a}: {a: ?number}) {
  if (a === undefined) a = 1;
  // ...
}
```

I'd definitely prioritize updating to a newer version of Flow, or these days even consider migrating to TS, considering how little the Flow team is able to focus on non-Facebook usage.

Comment: We've just learned that this bug seems to be scoped to defaulting destructured arguments. For example, this works in `0.79.1`:

`function foo(obj: {a: ?number} = {a: 1}) {}`